# #1060 - Duplicate column name 'NULL' CSV Product import

Tags: php, mysql, csv, import, importerror

I am COMPLETELY new to using CSV and PHPMyAdmin. I am attempting to move the product database from one zencart website to another. I went into the PHPMyAdmin on the original site and exported the files I need to a CSV file but when I try to import it to the new site I get this error

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `navaraa1_test`.`TABLE 97` (

`categories_id` VARCHAR( 11 ) ,
`language_id` VARCHAR( 13 ) ,
`categories_name` VARCHAR( 64 ) ,
`categories_description` VARCHAR( 63152 ) ,
`NULL` VARCHAR( 46 ) ,
`NULL` VARCHAR( 15 ) ,
`NULL` VARCHAR( 16 ) ,
`NULL` VARCHAR( 19 ) ,
`NULL` VARCHAR( 22 ) ,
`NULL` VARCHAR( 23 ) ,
`NULL` VARCHAR( 15 ) ,
`NULL` VARCHAR( 15 ) ,
`NULL` VARCHAR( 21 ) ,
`NULL` VARCHAR( 16 ) ,
`NULL` VARCHAR( 16 ) ,
`NULL` VARCHAR( 27 ) ,
`NULL` VARCHAR( 29 ) ,
`NULL` VARCHAR( 28 ) ,
`NULL` VARCHAR( 15 ) ,
`NULL` VARCHAR( 15 ) ,
`NULL` VARCHAR( 23 ) ,
`NULL` VARCHAR( 31 ) ,
`NULL` VARCHAR( 23 ) ,
`NULL` VARCHAR( 27 ) ,
`NULL` VARCHAR( 19 ) ,
`NULL` VARCHAR( 22 ) ,
`NULL` VARCHAR( 27 ) ,
`NULL` VARCHAR( 21 ) ,
`NULL` VARCHAR( 20 ) ,
`NULL` VARCHAR( 32 ) ,
`NULL` VARCHAR( 21 ) ,
`NULL` VARCHAR( 29 ) ,
`NULL` VARCHAR( 21 ) ,
`NULL` VARCHAR( 21 ) ,
`NULL` VARCHAR( 29 )
) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> #1060 - Duplicate column name 'NULL'

I have no idea what to do. I've tried reading similar posts but nothing helped. Thanks in advance if you can help1

Comment: `NULL` as  column name weird.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you forgot to specify all the field names in the first line of the CSV file, then they were like 'NULL' value. You should put different names for each column.

Comment: So as far as I could tell the columns did have names, and when i exported i clicked "put columns names in first row." However, i was trying to export multiple categories at once so I ended up doing them one by one and the import went through. Now my problem is all those categories that I imported seem to be empty and my products aren't showing up even though when I opened the files in excel they had all my information. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to name a number of columns `NULL` which is pretty weird.. you could come up with different names for each of these columns.

Comment: When I open it up in excel, none of the columns are named that.

Comment: Do they have names at all? `NULL` is a keyword for undefined data.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the values column/row do not contain `,` otherwise MySQL will generate new columns for each comma.